# change application palette run-time, without restarting the application

Tags: c++, qt

I am successfully using a dark theme for "fusion" style for Qt5 application. I would like to add the feature to switch the theme. If the user is required to restart the application there is not problem with this, the palette is correctly initialized at application start-up. But I would like to be able to do this run-time, without restarting. Most of widgets support this possibility but some other (e.g. `QComboBox`, `QSpinBox`, `QTreeView`) don't.  This can be proved by the following snippet - just press the button 'Reset style' and you can see how some parts of widgets change correctly but other parts don't. I am using the latest Qt 5.10 on Windows 10. This seems to me as Qt bug but is there any workaround or hack?

This is my `main.cpp`:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // apply the dark color scheme
    qApp->setStyle("fusion");
    QPalette darkPalette;
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Window,QColor(53,53,53));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::WindowText,Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled,QPalette::WindowText,QColor(127,127,127));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Base,QColor(42,42,42));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::AlternateBase,QColor(66,66,66));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::ToolTipBase,Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::ToolTipText,Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Text,Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled,QPalette::Text,QColor(127,127,127));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Dark,QColor(35,35,35));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Shadow,QColor(20,20,20));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Button,QColor(53,53,53));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::ButtonText,Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled,QPalette::ButtonText,QColor(127,127,127));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::BrightText,Qt::red);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Link,QColor(42,130,218));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight,QColor(42,130,218));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled,QPalette::Highlight,QColor(80,80,80));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText,Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled,QPalette::HighlightedText,QColor(127,127,127));
    qApp->setPalette(darkPalette);

    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This is `widget.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

};
```

and `widget.cpp`:

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStyleFactory>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    auto comboBox = new QComboBox();
    auto spinBox = new QSpinBox();
    auto listWidget = new QTreeWidget();
    listWidget->setHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "Column1" << "Column2");
    auto button = new QPushButton("Reset style");

    // reset the palette to the default 'light' color scheme
    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, 
            [] { qApp->setPalette(QStyleFactory::create("fusion")->standardPalette()); });

    layout->addWidget(comboBox);
    layout->addWidget(spinBox);
    layout->addWidget(listWidget);
    layout->addWidget(button);
}
```

This is the dark one:

[image]

and this after resetting the style:

[image]

UPDATE: This bug has been reported to Qt and already fixed. Well done, Qt team.

Comment: I logged this as a bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65475

Comment: If anyone else there who trying to change theme by their own stylesheet. Setting stylesheet again did it for me(Qt 5.12, Windows 10). `qApp->setStyleSheet(qApp->styleSheet());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discussion in this bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65475 the problem seems related to the pixmap caching done in some styles. The appropriate pixmaps are not cleared from the global QPixmapCache after changing the palette.

A possible workaround would be to manually clear the complete QPixmapCache:

```
QPixmapCache::clear();
```

With the obvious performance impact, in case a lot of pixmaps have to be recalculated.

Comment: Seems to work for me. I will use this workaround until the bug is fixed. Recalculation of pixmaps is not a problem, this operation is not performance critical and does not happen very often.